# Table column resize going wrong

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I tried to impelement the jQuery-UI plugin to resize a table column via Drag and Drop.

I got this:

```
$("#table,#table table tr th,#table table tr td").resizable({
     handles: 'e'
});
```

The dragging is working and it is changing the size, but in the beginning then I click between the 2 table columns and move the mouse a bit, the column width gets much bigger

I dont know how to solve this problem ... Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example code, consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("table").resizable();
  $("table thead th").resizable({
    handles: 'e'
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table th {
  background: #CCC;
  width: 120px;
  min-width: 2em;
}

table thead tr .ui-resizable-e {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 2px;
  height: 17px;
  background: #666;
  top: 1px;
  right: -2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>H1</th>
      <th>H2</th>
      <th>H3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td>B2</td>
      <td>C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A3</td>
      <td>B3</td>
      <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This allows the user to resize the header, and by proxy of the table structure, the columns are sized.

Hope this helps.